# Strange integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, bugs, evaluation, symbolic

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and fixed in 10.1**

Note: Beginning with V10.1, this integral returns unevaluated but without error messages.

---

I tried to evaluate this line

```
Integrate[((-I/2) (E^((-I) x) - E^(I x)) + ((E^((-I) x) + E^(I x)) x)/
     2)/((-1 + E^x) x), {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

Then I get $14$ lines of

```
$RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>
```

After that the anwer is

```
1/2 (-HarmonicNumber[-I] - HarmonicNumber[I])
```

After an `N[%]` is gives `-0.671866 + 0. I`, but this is an incorrect answer, since the correct numerical value of the integral is `-0.39629064109001017515941014`.

Maybe *Mathematica* couldn't solve it, it's ok, but from where comes this incorrect closed expression?

By the way of turned `Off` something and because of this the evaluation does not stop after run into some $RecursionLimit, but I don't know what was that and I cannot turn it `On`. Any idea what was that? I forgot it.

I use *Mathematica 9*.

Comment: which version are you using? on V10.01, I do not get `1/2 (-HarmonicNumber[-I] - HarmonicNumber[I])`, but only `Recursion depth`. btw, doing `NIntegrate[...]` works and gives `-0.396291 + 1.65436*10^-24 I` which is the correct numerical value that you show there. screen shot: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eCln4.png)

Comment: @Nasser I use *Mathematica 9.* Yes, but it is strange that `NIntegrate[...]` and `N[Integrate[...]]` are different.

Comment: FYI the expression simplifies to: `(Cos[x]-Sinc[x])/(Cosh[x]+Sinh[x]-1)`.  Same result on integration though :(

Comment: @george2079 Thank you. I've known it, but *Mathematica* makes more recursion for this form.

Comment: `$RecursionLimit = Infinity;` causes it to keep running..not optimistic it will yield a result though.

Comment: Definitely a bug.

Comment: Adding the [tag:bugs] tag (per Daniel); one would reasonably expect not to encounter a `$RecursionLimit`-related error for an integration.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. In V10.2, the integral returns unevaluated with no messages (after a good, long, think).  I guess that counts as "fixed"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way of evaluating your integral analytically.

Series expand the integrand, but hold out a factor `x/(-1 + E^x)` to ensure that the series can subsequently be integrated term by term — this factor is `1` at `x = 0`, and `x E^-x` as `x -> Infinity`. Keep only the first few terms of the series, which we will use to “spot the pattern”.

```
ser = Series[(x Cos[x] - Sin[x])/((-1 + E^x) x) ((-1 + E^x)/x), {x, 0, 6}] //
  Normal // # x/(-1 + E^x) & // Expand

(* -(x^2/(3 (-1 + E^x))) + x^4/(30 (-1 + E^x)) - x^6/(840 (-1 + E^x)) *)
```

By integrating each term of this series it is easy to spot that integration of the general term can be done using the following rule:

```
rule = (x^b_ a_)/(-1+E^x) :> a b! Zeta[b+1];
```

Feed the (truncated) series through this rule.

```
ser /. rule

(* -((2 Zeta[3])/3) + (4 Zeta[5])/5 - (6 Zeta[7])/7 *)
```

The pattern is obvious, so the required integral is given by (this takes a while to evaluate)

```
int = Sum[(-1)^i (2 i)/(2 i + 1) Zeta[2 i + 1], {i, \[Infinity]}] // FunctionExpand

(* 1/2 I Log[Gamma[1 - I]] - 1/2 I Log[Gamma[1 + I]]
  - 1/2 PolyGamma[0, 1 - I] - 1/2 PolyGamma[0, 1 + I] *)
```

The numerical value of this symbolic result is

```
N[int] // Chop

(* -0.396291 *)
```

which is the same as is obtained by direct numerical integration.

Comment: @ Stephen Lutrell: Your final sum does not converge in V8. After regularizing it with Exp(-a i) and taking the limit a->0 of the then converging sum gives the expected result +0. I. The different expansion 1/(E^x - 1) == Sum[E^(x (-k - 1)), {k, 0, \[Infinity]}] leads to the Sum[(1 + k)/(2 + k*(2 + k)) - ArcTan[1/(1 + k)], {k, 0, Infinity}] the NSum of which gives the result in no time.

Comment: Based on a `ListPlot` of the terms in my `Sum` I had assumed that there must be subtle tricks going on behind the scenes in V10 in order for it to get its result to come out - in fact, I was rather surprised that it worked at all.

Comment: BTW, I like your use of the `1/(1-z) == Sum[z^k, {k, 0, \[Infinity]}]` trick.

Comment: @ Stephen Lutrell: things are even more interesting! Your sum is in fact divergent by all criteria. Define the partial sum by s[m_] := Sum[(2*(-1)^k*k*Zeta[1 + 2*k])/(1 + 2*k), {k, 1, m}]. It oscillates between two values, depending on the parity of m: s[10^4] // N -> 0.103684, s[10^4 + 1] // N -> -0.896266 and only the average of these two gives the "correct result". A more simple example is Sum[(-1)^k,{k,0,oo}] which gives 1/2 "on average". Hence the well defined and "innocent" original integral provides de facto a regularized divergent infinite sum.